# how to put impact radius cURL command in php

Tags: php, curl

I know how to call cURL in php but I am confused to run the following Impact provided details for their catalog. Please help me put following into php code, many thanks. these are Impact Radius API.
https://integrations.impact.com/impact-publisher/reference/search-catalog-items

```
curl 'https://api.impact.com/Mediapartners/<AccountSID>/Catalogs/ItemSearch' \
  -X GET \
  -u '<AccountSID>:<AuthToken>' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -d 'Query=CurrentPrice>=12.00ANDStockAvailability!=OutOfStock' \
  -d 'Keyword=Acme' \
  -G
```

I tried following, but no luck

```
$accountSID = "xyz";
$authToken = "xyz";

$url = "https://api.impact.com/Mediapartners/".$accountSID."/Catalogs/ItemSearch";
$url .= "?Query=CurrentPrice>=12.00ANDStockAvailability!=OutOfStock";

$curl_connection = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $accountSID . ":" . $authToken);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt ($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);  //Force requsts to use TLS 1.2
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

$output = curl_exec($curl_connection);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl_connection,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    
    if($output){
        curl_close($curl_connection);
        echo $output;die;
    } else {
        echo $error = curl_errno($curl_connection);
        curl_close($curl_connection);
        die;
    }
```

Comment: What do you get out of the PHP code, does it show any errors?  Is there any content returned?

Comment: Why are you setting a `Content-Type: application/json` request header, that was not part of the native cURL command you have shown. (Not sure how much it matters on a GET request though.)

Comment: And where is `Keyword=Acme`?

Comment: Thanks everybody for your response, It works fine now. the issue was wrong Auth token